# Why does my op-amp circuit output a rectangle wave form instead of sine?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, pulse, proteus, waveform

After tons of research on the web I still don't know what the problem is.

I'm trying to simulate a non-inverting voltage amplifier.  It is supposed to generate a similar waveform but when I use the oscilloscope I see that the wave is a rectangle not a sine wave.

Can someone explain what is wrong?

The first picture is wrong I know but it is just for experimenting the op-amp.
[image: my real-time output]

[image: the full picture]

Comment: Because that is not an non inverting amplifier. It has no feedback to reign in the output and is wired as a comparator.

Comment: If you want a non-inverting amplifier that outputs a waveform similar to the input, then you need to connect the feedback to give you a unity gain buffer. At the moment, it's connected as a comparator, which will output a sqaure wave.

Comment: The op-amp is not connected correctly to be an amplifier, it is connected to be a comparator.

Comment: What are the power supply voltages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, your first diagram has the opamp wired as a comparator, not a linear feedback amplifier.

Your second diagram has the classical inverting and non-inverting resistive feedback configurations. Still, they are saturating because you are using gains with magnitudes of -10 and +11, yet you're driving a 5V signal into them (at least, that's how I read your software oscilloscope display). The power supply appears to b 12.5 V. But your input amplitude multiplied by the closed-loop gain exceeds the power supply, which of course the amp can't do. Try reducing your input amplitude to, say 0.5 V, and then experiment with it.

Answer (score 2):

Because your circuit is missing *negative* feedback, the input is driving the op-amp into saturation. First at the high rail. Then at the low rail.

Edit: in your second picture, either your gain is too high, or your supply voltages are too low. Again, the reason for the near square wave output is saturation of the op amp.

Comment: I'm sorry for not giving the full picture but I have made a real non inverting circuit before that one but it is also outputs a square wave. that small pic is just for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The "operational" in "operational amplifier" means that it's designed to be very versatile at making circuits do various mathematical operations.  In order to achieve this, op-amps, by themselves, have very high voltage gain -- usually \$10^5\$ or \$10^6\$.  They are designed so that when you wrap them with negative feedback, the gain is so high that it overwhelms the non-ideal nature of the amplifier so that the circuit characteristics are determined by the feedback, not the amplifier.

In the first circuit you show, you need feedback.  Do a web search on "operational amplifier circuits", or "building amplifiers with op-amps".  You should get plenty of hits on useful little circuits.

In the second two circuits, you're setting your gains to +11 and -10, respectively.  Then you're putting in a \$\pm 5\mathrm{V}\$ sine wave.  Perfect amplifiers would deliver \$\pm 55\mathrm{V}\$ and \$\pm50\mathrm{V}\$, but your supplies are limited -- it looks like they're \$15\mathrm V\$ supplies with real op-amp models, or \$12 \mathrm V\$ supplies with ideal but voltage limited op-amp models.  Either way, your amplifiers are saturating, because they can't deliver more voltage than they're given on their supplies.

Those two second circuits *should* work if you choose input voltages that are less than 12V/11 and 12V/10, respectively.  So -- try again, with \$\pm 1\mathrm V\$.

Comment: i edited the question can you give me a second opinion. thanks in advance.